# Placing Buttons on a Circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm having a heck of a time calculating points on a circle in Objective-C. Even after reading TONS of other code samples my circle is still way off center. (And that's taking into consideration "center" vs "origin" and adjusting for the size of the UIView, in this case a UIButton.)

Here's the code I'm using. The circle is formed correctly, it's just off center. I'm not sure if this is a radians vs degrees problem or something else. This is a helper function in a ViewController that programmatically creates the UIButtons and adds them to the view:

```
- (CGPoint)pointOnCircle:(int)thisPoint withTotalPointCount:(int)totalPoints {
    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    float radius = 100.0;
    float angle = ( 2 * M_PI / (float)totalPoints ) * (float)thisPoint;
    CGPoint newPoint;
    newPoint.x = (centerPoint.x / 2) + (radius * cosf(angle));
    newPoint.y = (centerPoint.y / 2) + (radius * sinf(angle));
    return newPoint;   
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The center of your buttons (i.e. points on the circle) is

```
newPoint.x = (centerPoint.x) + (radius * cosf(angle));  // <= removed / 2
newPoint.y = (centerPoint.y) + (radius * sinf(angle));  // <= removed / 2
```

Please note that if you place buttons (i.e. rectangles) on these points you have to make sure that their center lies at this point (i.e. subtract `buttonWidth/2` from `newPoint.x` and `buttonHeight/2` from `newPoint.y` to get the top left corner).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason I had the /2 in there is because that brought me much closer to the center of the screen (though still off). Without dividing the centerPoint by 2, the circle gets plotted halfway off the screen to the bottom right.

Comment: Oh, and yes I am adjusting the placement of the buttons to use the return value as the center rather than the origin.

Comment: Argh! Ok, (1) I'm an idiot. (2) You guys rock. It turns out that I was adjusting the placement of the buttons incorrectly - rather than subtracting half the width and height, I was adding. I made a test harness with just the button generation code and it works perfectly. My actual app is still placing the circle off center but I'm closer to tracking down why that is. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you divide by 2 a second time newPoint coordinates...

What about this:

```
newPoint.x = centerPoint.x + (radius * cosf(angle));
newPoint.y = centerPoint.y + (radius * sinf(angle));
return newPoint;
```